# Trying to append child to all elements with same class name

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use the `appendChild()` method to add a `document.createElement("div")` element to multiple `<div>` elements with the same class name.

I have tried this way:

```
const childElement = document.createElement("div");
childElement.className = "second";
const parentObject = document.getElementsByClassName("first");

[...parentObject].map(parent => parent.appendChild(childElement))
```

Which didnt work, so I tried:

```
for(let i = 0; i < parentObject.length; i++){
  parentObject[i].appendChild(childElement);
}
```

The only way it worked was if I wrote the html element myself and then added it to the innerHTML of each parent:

```
[...parentObject].map(parent => parent.innerHTML = "<div class='second'></div>")
```

But since I am generating all different kind of HTML element tags, like `IMG, DIV, SPAN` I need the convenience of calling the `createElement()` method.

Has anyone any experience with this?

Comment: You want to append *multiple* elements. Create one for each parent that you want to add to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An element can only exist in one place in the DOM. What you need to do is create a new element to append to each parent:

```js
const parentObject = document.getElementsByClassName('first');

[...parentObject].forEach((parent, i) => {
  const childElement = document.createElement('div');
  childElement.className = 'second';
  childElement.innerHTML = `second ${i}`;
  parent.appendChild(childElement)
});
```

```css
div { padding: 5px; }
.first { background-color: pink; display: inline-block; }
.second { background-color: lightblue; }
```

```html
<div class="first">first</div>
<div class="first">first</div>
<div class="first">first</div>
<div class="first">first</div>
```

Comment: Instead of doing that weird `[...parentObject].map`, just use a `for (const parent of parentObject) {` loop

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Agreed. Soon [`NodeList.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) will be widely supported and it won't be necessary.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes, but it's inefficient, misleading and unnecessary. Also `map` shouldn't be used when one doesn't want to create an array. Just use a plain simple imperative loop instead of callbacks.

Comment: I am just used to mapping, since I use a lot of inheritance in my JS classes and dont want to use foreach, since I would have to bing `this`

Comment: @Jousi You seem to have picked up a misconception somewhere. `map` and `forEach` have identical `this` semantics. Literally the only difference between the two is that `map` returns a new Array and `forEach` returns `undefined`.

Comment: But when I use `foreach` and I insert a variable such as `this.value`, which I define in a constructor, then `this` wont get binded with the class, then I have to bind it using `let that = this` for example

Comment: @Jousi `Array.prototype.map` works exactly the same way as `Array.prototype.forEach`. If you can show me otherwise in a JSFiddle I would be very interested to see it. (Also, both `map` and `forEach` take a second `thisArg` argument, so `let that = this` is never necessary.)

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, and I certainly didnt know that you can bind `this` directly in one of the `foreach` arguments. I just know that before I started using ES6, whenever I wanted to pass a `this.variable` in a foreach loop, I had to bind it outside the loop

Comment: this is what I meant [link](https://jsfiddle.net/aw22jwyf/) . I forgot that I had to bind `this` but only when using the `call()` method @JordanRunning

Comment: @Jousi Setting aside the fact that you're seriously misusing `call`, can you show me how `map` behaves any differently in this example?

Comment: Well in `map()` I could use `this` and no `that = this` like so: `[...this.elements].map(el => {
      el.innerHTML = this.value;
    });`

Comment: @Jousi That works because you're using an arrow function (`=>`), not because of `map`. `forEach` works identically.